# UIWebView swipe gesture after pan gesture

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working on an IOS app that uses a navigation controller to present a table view that contains a list of articles from a web site. Taping one of the entries in this table triggers a segue into a view that contains a UIWebView, which displays the web page for this article.

Now, within the web view I have added a gesture recognizer for a swipe-right gesture. This gesture triggers a method that pops the current view from the navigation controller's stack, hence allowing the user to navigate back to the list of articles using this gesture. The problem I'm running into, however, is that if the webpage is zoomed in (so that the user must scroll left/right to view all of the pages contents) the pan gesture for the UIWebView overrides my swipe gesture.

I've read through quite a few different ideas of how to deal with this, but none of them seem to achieve what I want. The closet I've come is by implementing the UIGestureRecognitionDelegate protocol and adding the following to my code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)paner shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swiper
{
    return YES;
}
```

This does indeed allow both the pan gesture and the swipe gesture, but as the method name implies, they occur simultaneously. This means that the user is unable to pan to the right because it will also recognize this as a swipe gesture and hence return them to the article list.

So, my question is, what would be the best way to allow for both the pan gesture and the swipe gesture? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This strikes me as more of a user-experience question than a programming question, might be a good fit for http://ux.stackexchange.com. My opinion would be to let pan override swipe when zoomed in, as that seems the least-surprising behavior - being zoomed in is a special, deliberate state. Alternatively, use a two-finger swipe to return to the list, so you're not in conflict with the pan gesture.

Comment: I think if you want only one or the other you should use requireGestureRecognizerToFail: on the more specific one as a condition for the generic one to be triggered.